# Помощь в подмене символа на слово

Tags: php, html, mysql

Я недавно начал разбиратся в php, после того как разобрался в html и css, и сразу встал в ступор.

И так, у меня имеется подключенная база mysql к php
и имеется такой код.

```
$table .= "<tr>";
$table .= "<td>Статус аккаунта:</td>";
$table .= "<td>".$row['Online']."</td>";
$table .= "</tr>";
```

Как только кто то заходит на аккаунт в таблице mysql в колонке Online вместо "-" ставится "1"
И мне надо сделать подмену что бы вместо "1" было слово online
А вместо символа "-" было offline.

p.s. пробовал через else if но не получилось.

Comment: обычное условие не подходит? `$status = 'offline'; status = $row['Online'] == 1 ? 'Online' : 'Offline';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$status = "Offline";
if($row['Online'])
 $status = "Online";
$table .= "<tr>";
$table .= "<td>Статус аккаунта:</td>";
$table .= "<td>".$status."</td>";
$table .= "</tr>";
```

Как то так

Comment: Огромное спасибо,очень помог. :)